# How do I correctly set up a publisher-subscriber architecture using MassTransit with MSMQ?

Tags: msmq, publish-subscribe, masstransit

How do I correctly set up a publisher-subscriber architecture with multiple subscribers (which all receive a published message) using MassTransit and MSMQ.

Note that I do not want to use the MSMQ multicast feature as it is a bit flaky and relies on PGM (which has some restrictions of its own).

I have read [this](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/overview/subscriptions.html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802678/masstransit-msmq-pub-with-multi-sub-when-is-runtimeservices-ready) and [this](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2012/08/03/quick-start-on-mass-transit-and-msmq-on-windows/) but still cannot figure out how I should setup

1. the subscription service,
2. a publisher,
3. and a couple of subscribers.

In particular the `sbc.UseSubscriptionService("uri");` which is used in many examples is now obsolete (I am using MassTransit 2.7). The obsolete comment says `The extension method on UseMsmq should be used instaed`, but I cannot find such a method.
How are we supposed to setup up the subscription service?

The [Distributor](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/master/src/Samples) sample on the MassTransit Github page gets closest to what I want but it sets up consuming subscribers.

Please point me to or provide a example of how to setup a publisher-subscriber architecture where multiple subscribers are possible.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

To use the UseSubscriptionService extension method you need to import the MSMQ configuration namespace.

```
Imports MassTransit.Transports.Msmq.Configuration
```

you can now write this (VB.Net)

```
sbc.UseMsmq(Sub(c)
    c.UseSubscriptionService(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MassTransit_SubscriptionService"))
End Sub)
```

That's for configuring the Service, but in order to make everything work correctly (using MSMQ) you need to have the MassTransit Runtime Service running (latest version available from [GitHub MassTransit Runtime Services](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/master/src/MassTransit.RuntimeServices); you'll need this one instead of the one available from the binaries on the MassTransit website, those are outdated).

Once you have downloaded the source, you should run SetupSQLServer.sql first.
Next is adjusting the config file to point to your database and use the correct credentials.
You should now run this program (as console during dev, but best installed as windows service in non-dev environments). Make sure the console is before starting your publishers/subscribers since they depend on this 'service'.

I have just now realized a fully functional setup and experienced my moment of bliss. I intend to do a full write-up of all my steps, but I hope this helps a bit already.

[This article explains the setup of the Runtimeservice in a little more detail.](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2012/08/03/quick-start-on-mass-transit-and-msmq-on-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

I think "sets up consuming subscribers" is the give away as to the source of your difficulty - all subscribers are "consuming subscribers".

The best way to think about MassTransit is in terms of fan-out: MassTransit maintains routes to all consumers interested in certain type of message. You setup one or more consumer at one or more endpoints and MassTransit makes sure a *copy* of the message gets to each consumer.

Distributor is actually a specialized case where this is intentionally not true and not one you should be looking at, unless you're interested in load-balancing.
Here's the relevant docs link: http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/master/overview/publishing.html#plain-msmq